# Schengen visa applying in France but entering into Italy?

Tags: schengen, customs-and-immigration, schengen-visas, itineraries

**Initial Itinerary**: (**Entry**) Italy (3 days) -> Switzerland (3 days) -> France (6 days) -> Netherlands (3 days) (**Exit**)

With the initial plan, I have to apply for Schengen visa in the French consulate. Now, after I get the visa, what if I need to change the itinerary to the following

---

**Updated Itinerary**: (**Entry**) Italy (5 days) -> Switzerland (3 days) -> France (2 days) -> Netherlands(3 days) (**Exit**)

---

In this case. What will the immigration officer ask when I enter Italy with a Schengen visa issued in France? Notice that I just change the number of days I stay in each country. Will this be a problem?

**EDIT**: For clarification.

The simpler question in my mind is, what if you like a place a lot, and intend to stay there longer, and vice versa, what if you don't like a place and want to move on to the next destination. This will result in change in the number of days declared per country during visa application.

Comment: It may be a problem, especially if the French consulate has faster visa processing or is otherwise more convenient than the Italian consulate. The suspicion would be that the original itinerary was a fake and you always intended the new one.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan That makes total sense. But, my question was more from the direction of, what if you don't like a place after you visit there, and want to move on to the next destination earlier than intended? I should have composed the question in a better way.

Comment: @Parthapratim Neog FWIW, a 13 day itinerary taking in 4 European countries (each of whom easily warrant that amount of time in their own right) means you’ll spend quite a lot of time travelling rather than actually experiencing the destinations.

Comment: @Traveller My itinerary is actually of 17 days. The days mentioned in the question are just to simplify it.

Answer (score 3):

In principle the change of itinerary might give rise to a suspicion that you never intended for France to be your main destination but just claimed so because it was somehow more convenient for you to submit your application to the French consulate. If that is the case your visa may be annulled.

*In practice* it doesn't appear to be very likely that the border guards at entry will demand so detailed documentation that they'll discover the change of itinerary. But it *could* happen, and it's up to you whether to risk it or not.

Comment: I see how this might look bad. Thank you for the answer.